# Toggle between two sylesheets with radio button

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to have a toggle button to switch between a light and dark theme. I can toggle once but it doesn't toggle back after. My current approach is this:

```
<link id="theme-css" class="dark-theme" rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/dashboard-dark.css' %}">

<div class="custom-control custom-switch">
  <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="customSwitches" onclick="toggle()">
  <label class="custom-control-label" for="customSwitches">Toggle Theme</label>
</div>

<script>
    function toggle() {
      if(document.getElementById("theme-css").href="{% static 'css/dashboard-dark.css' %}"){
        document.getElementById("theme-css").href="{% static 'css/dashboard-light.css' %}"; 
      }
      else if(document.getElementById("theme-css").href="{% static 'css/dashboard-light.css' %}"){
        document.getElementById("theme-css").href="{% static 'css/dashboard-dark.css' %}"; 
      }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Instead of having two <link> elements in the document, you can have just one and control its "href" attribute value with javascript.

Comment: @MarkSkayff I have updated my post

Comment: You can prepend a class name for themes and load both files. Then you can toggle the body class. Like .dashboard-dark .style {} and .dashboard-light .style {} and <body="dashboard-dark"> etc.. Your css will be larger but you may lose the loading effect while changing themes.

Comment: based on your code, the if statement will always evaluate to true because you are doing assignment not checking for equality using `==` or `===`

Comment: What is that `{% %}` template like syntax? Is that a template engine syntax for the backend, or is that frontend syntax? I think whatever it is you should use the final result of the engine parsing.

Comment: @MarkSkayff Those are Django template tags

Comment: @Ma'mounothman If I do that, no changes happen

Comment: You cannot check against the django template tags. You have to check against the actual values behind those. Check my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Let's see. First to note you are looking for a **toggle** type functionality. 
When you do a toggle you want to keep state somewhere. Whether on an html element itself or within javascript object.

I would load the script with an initial state for a theme. Let's say the light theme and store that value within a javascript variable.

So, everytime the toggle function is called, you query the js variable state, and you swap the themes according to that.

So you would do something like this:

```
// Some variable called state holds the theme state
var link = document.getElementById("theme-css");
if(state == 'light')
     link.href = "<the-dark-uri-css-path>";
else
     link.href = "<the-light-uri-css-path>";
// The you toggle the state val
state = state=='light'? 'dark' : 'light';
```

Remember you can build this as an object and keep the state of the theme within an object property.